# Pandas search a dataframe for substrings using the values from a separate dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've gone around with this but can't seem to get it right.  Basically I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple sheets, for this python program I only care about two of the sheets, and more specifically one column from each sheet.

I want to take all of the values from one dataframe/column (A) and see if a second dataframe/column (B) contains a substring of that value from column A.  Ultimately I want a csv output containing the rows from column A where the value from column A does not have a substring match in column B.

So I've got this so far

Reading in the excel file and creating two dataframes each using the column I'm interested in:

```
df_A = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',
        sheet_name='Sheet_1',
        usecols=['Column_A'])

df_B = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',
        sheet_name='Sheet_2',
        usecols=['Column_B'])
```

Here are the contents of the dataframes:

```
Column_A
20220201_ABC_TEST-00012345_987654
20220201_ABC_TEST-00012346_987654
20220201_ABC_TEST-00012347_987654
20220201_ABC_TEST-00012351_987654
20220201_ABC_TEST-00012352_987654
20220201_ABC_TEST-00012353_987654

Column_B
TEST-00012345
TEST-00012346
TEST-00012347
TEST-00012348
TEST-00012349
TEST-00012350
```

And this is the part that I don't know how to do properly, that is take all the values from df_A and comparing them to all the values in df_B to find out which values from df_A don't have substring matches in df_B.

```
substring_matches = df_A.str.contains(df_B)
print(substring_matches)
```

This gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

So something I'm doing is not quite right here.

Comment: Please provide the two dataframes in text format. But very likely you need to loop

Comment: `.str` will work on a column (Series) but not on a full DF.

Comment: @mozway I added the contents of the dataframes

Comment: Adding to @jch, you can't pass a full DataFrame or Series to `.str.contains()`, just a single string. What's your desired output?

Comment: @scespinoza I edited my question a bit to add a little more clarity on what I'm looking for the final output, but basically what you gave me allowed me to have an output of True/False.  Now I'm just trying to figure out how to output the rows from Column A where there aren't any matches in Column B into a separate csv file just containing the values from Column A that don't match.

Comment: I think `df_A[~substring_matches].to_csv('unmatched.csv')` should do that for you

Comment: Is the `TEST-00012345` part always in between `_` and the full format in A consistent (`something_TEST-numbers_something-else`)?

Comment: @scespinoza thanks for that it works now!  I marked your original answer as correct, I don't know if there is a way to add your second part to the original answer.

Comment: @Pete I added the line. I thought you were only seeking for the `substring_matches` output. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
substring_matches = df_A['Column_A'].apply(lambda s1: df_B['Column B'].apply(lambda s2: s2 in s1).any())
df_A[~substring_matches].to_csv('unmatched.csv')
```